# Why bootstrap 5. 0 Modal doesn't work nor appear

Tags: php, html, bootstrap5-modal

Can you help me fix the modal, I'm using a anchor tag for my bootstrap modal but it doesn't work.
What seems to be the problem?
'''

```
<div class="p border-top py-3">Doesn't have an account yet? <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Create an account</a></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
         <div class="modal-content">
             ...
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change to data-bs-toggle, data-bs-target

```
<div class="p border-top py-3">Doesn't have an account yet? <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalCenter">Create an account</a></div>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
         ..
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```